# How to enable style attribute for each tag in ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

How can I enabled style attributes in ckeditor5?

I have style attributes in old ckeditor4, so to migrate it to new version, I need to support style attribute.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell CkEditor5 what each of the style attributes mean, and it will parse the style attributes for you.

If you install the font plugin (which for some bizarre reason isn't in the default build), then CkEditor can read and write the font-family and font-size attributes. Install the Alignment plugin and it can read text-align - and so on.